# How to perform one async action after another without embedded subscriptions

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable, subscription

I would like to perform async actions one after another using rxjs. I know that embedding subscribe in a subscribe is not a good practice and there are some other rxjs operators (**flatMap\mergeMap, do** etc. using **pipe**).

I need to get the component queryparams, set a global variable (globalVar), and **only then**, continue with the next async action (this..doSomething()).
This is my code using embedded subscriptions:
*doSomething return an observable

```
this.route.paramMap.subscribe(params => 
    { 
      globalVar = + params['userId']; 
      this.<someService>.doSomething().subscribe(result => 
      {
        this.func1();
      });
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A perfect solution for the cases where you want to chain multiple observables is the `switchMap` operator.

```js
this.route.paramMap
    .pipe(
      switchMap(params) => {
      globalVar = + params['userId']; 
      return this.<someService>.doSomething()
    })
    .subscribe(result=> {this.func1();})
```

The thing that `switchMap` will do is after getting the params from the `this.route` it will return a new observable, for which you can latter subscribe. The benefit of using `switchMap` in this case is that if there are changes inside the `this.route.paramMap` while the `this.<someService>.doSomething()` is processed, rxjs will kill the request that is being processed and start new one, by doing so the date in **result** inside the `subscribe` will always be relevant to the current value of `paramMap`.

Answer (score 1):

```
this.route.paramMap.pipe(
  switchMap(params => {
    globalVar = + params['userId'];
    return this.<someService>.doSomething().pipe(
      tap(() => this.func1())
    )
  })
).subscribe();
```

Comment: verbal explanations are usually helpful too

Answer (score 0):

Async/await would be a way to make your code readable in the way that it can be read sequential. That is my preferred route after i also tried embedding observable over a few levels.